# explicitly calling ~boost::lock_guard<> causes mutex deadlock

Tags: boost, mutex

if this is a bug I have no problem just not doing it, but if this is an expected behaviour I would like to know why.

I do something like this:

```
{
   boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lg(tagsToSocketsMtx);
// mutex protected work 
   lg.~lock_guard(); // this causes deadlocks later(combined with ...
  //...other uses of the same mtx, ofc I use different lock guard in other functions)

// rest of the function
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the construction of `lg` completes, C++ guarantees that its destructor will be called on scope exit *regardless of the fact that you're are also making an explicit destructor call*.

By destroying `lg` twice, you are invoking undefined behaviour, and in this case the bug manifests as a deadlock.

Comment: ouch... i thought that this just moves destruction fwd, but now when i think about it it is in general impossible to determine if explicit  destructor will be called (if it is inside if statement)...  so yeah Im stupid... BTW why does C++ allow explicit calling of dtors? It seems like a horrible idea. Could delete be given special rights so it can call dtor, but users cant ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: A typically use of explicit destructor calls (when paired with placement new) is to separate object lifetime from memory allocation.

Comment: tnx, if somebody wonders why was I making such a stupid mistake... I remembered using a similar class from I think C++11 that had unlock method for perf reasons so when I didnt find it I called destructor explicitly. :/

Comment: "By destroying lg twice, you are invoking undefined behaviour", are you sure about that? It surely isn't the intended way to use a lock guard, but I don't think it's technically a UB to call the destructor (not delete) more than once.

Comment: @enobayram: "For an object with a non-trivial
destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor ﬁnishes
execution results in undeﬁned behavior".

Comment: I see, so the compiler is allowed to assume that the instance fields will never be referenced again (until a subsequent placement new?).

Comment: @enobayram: Yes, but a more useful consequence is that destructors don't have to be written in a way where multiple calls are safe.

Comment: This is a great commend thread (pun intended) and helped me solve my dead lock problem. I am wondering if any of you could point me to links where you found these standards discusses so that I can understand the problem more in depth. Thank you.